# Can I connect to a specific Enterprise architect model?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Using .NET, I'd like to connect to an EA model from an external application.

If I have more than one EA model open -- eg two remote SQL Server hosted models -- how do I specify extracting data from only one of the models?

```
# any way to specify a specific data source?
var r = new EA.Repository();

# As I don't think is what I want because:
# 1) didn't want to Open a document -- just connect to it
# 2) don't have a filename - just a model name and/or ConnString...
bool isOpen = r.OpenFile("C:/Sparx-EA/Test Project.EAP");

# etc.
Element ele = r.GetElementByID(10);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the [manual](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/repository3.html):

> OpenFile (string Filename) Boolean
>
> Notes: This is the main point for
> opening an Enterprise Architect project file from an automation
> client, and working with the contained objects.
> If the required
> project is a DBMS repository, and you have created a shortcut .eap
> file containing the database connection string, you can call this
> shortcut file to access the DBMS repository.
> You can also connect to a
> SQL database by passing in the connection string itself instead of a
> filename.
> A valid connection string can be obtained from the Open
> Project dialog by selecting a recently opened SQL repository.
> Parameters: Filename: String - the filename of the Enterprise
> Architect project to open

Answer (score 0):

`Repository.OpenFile()` is the correct method to use. You can pass it a connection string, it doesn't have to be a file.

A `Repository` object can only be connected to one EA project at a time. So in order to connect to two EA projects in the same process, create two `Repository` objects.

Finally, the numeric identities used in calls like `Repository.GetElementByID()` are valid only within a repository. The number 10 likely refers to two different elements in two repositories -- or might have been deleted in one of them. If you know you've got the same element in two repositories, use `Repository.GetElementByGuid()` instead.